# How to define a different name for each IP/NIC in the same PC

Tags: networking, netbios, wins

In a machine with multiple IP(s)
(all in the same subnet)
Using NETBIOS or WINS (no DNS)

I want to PING this machine
using a name for each IP (or a name for each NIC)

for example, this IP(s) are in the same computer: 
192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2

and I want to ping:

```
server1 for 192.168.0.1
server2 for 192.168.0.1
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Operating system?  Do you want to ping from other computers?  If so, where are the other computers and what are they running?  Is it really true that *all* you want to do is ping, or do you want to do other things, too?

Comment: hi Ben... the PC with the 2-or-more IP(s) is a Windows Server  (so can run WINS or use NETBIOS).... the other PC(s) that will PING are in the same LAN (and can have any OS with a TCP/IP stack) and same subnet... and remeber: if i can PING/ICMP then I can do other stuff....

Comment: Remember also that the automatic NETBIOS broadcasts are made in OSI/L2,,, and the WINS server works in OSI/L3... also I do not want to use DNS (it is easy to solve this with a DNS server)...

Comment: "if i can PING/ICMP then I can do other stuff"     ...    Not really.  In particular, the SMB services on Windows support mult-homing only to a limited extent, and disjoint naming not at all.  So, what are you actually trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to solve business need or implement a particular piece of software?

Comment: NetBEUI (no longer available in Windows, AFAIK) works exclusively in layer two, but NetBIOS-over-TCP/IP uses UDP to do name lookups.  Without WINS, it will do a UDP broadcast, but that is still IP and still involves layer three.

Comment: Ok Scott... NETBIOS without WINS broadcast in OSI/L2 for discovery purpouses... similar to DHCP discovery...  so... what I mean with "if I can PING..." was that I control this machines... I can install/config/etc.... I only need them to be available/addressable via IP. about the SMB... I have no problems and is not the original question... I use SMB in several networks mixing Windows+OSX+Linux+???... ???did i mentioned NETBEUI ??? I've used this protocol in Win9x times... but... ?did I mentioned it here ???

Comment: again... what I''m trying to accomplish is just have 2-or-more ip's in a windows 2003 server... and access each one of them from other PC's with a different name... WITHOUT DNS!

this has to do with a tweak I have to do between a mail service (POP3+SMTP), a mail screening AV and some fiddling with SSL+TLS... and I want to keep this system (LAN) undisturbed (not fiddling with OS or other installed software)... ;-)

Comment: Look, you can describe what you are trying to do, or you can dance around it with vague comments.  I don't care which, but I suspect you will get much better answers if you communicate better.  I, for one, am done trying to fight for the privilege of helping you for free.

Comment: I will explain again... trying to oversimplify:-> I want have 2 names, visible on a LAN, for a Windows PC... each name associated with their on IP... for example... in the this PC we have the IP(s) 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2, the name "Srv1" would resolve to 192.168.0.1... and the name "Srv2" would resolve to to 192.168.0.2... and I rest my case... I cannot make this more simplistic...

Answer (score 1):

Names and IP addresses are tied together in DNS. On your DNS server you can direct each name to a different IP address. It doesn't matter if it's on another machine or not.

With NetBIOS name resolution this won't work as each NIC/IP binding will respond and there's only a single name. WINS? Don't use WINS.

If all else fails you can edit the local `hosts` file to fake name resolution. This should be used as a last resort as it's a common source of trouble when entries are long forgotten.

Comment: Thx,,, I use DNS, WINS, NETBIOS, host-file, etc. and all solutions have their merits... the issue i'm asking here is just to avoid breaking changes in an old network (has NETBIOS name resolution, but I can update to WINS without fuss)... where I just want to have the functionality (as I use in DNS) to address (from other PC... So... no hosts-file solution works here) each IP with a different name... ;-)

Comment: NetBEUI uses its own `hosts`-file: `lmhosts`. Do check out whether DNS names don't work - every Windows since 2000 prefers DNS over WINS.